# D3.js tree with multiple parents and connected children

Tags: javascript, d3.js

is there anything to accomplish a tree like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZm3K.png) using D3.js (v3 or v4). I'd just like to have sth. like in my image with labels on hover for each element. There are some example for multiple parents but not exactly as in my example

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZm3K.png